# Get selected value id, from a mapped array via onClick event

Tags: arrays, reactjs, onclick

I have an app where you can search a specific company and the results that render will show you their employees.

My goal: is to be able to click on the employee name and pass that data to another component via click event, for now, I am just trying to isolate the value.

My problem: when I search for a company with more than one employee, I get all the employee's data in my consol.log and not the one I clicked on. For example, if I search for "Target", my results are "Jane and Kerk, when I click on Jane my console should be "Jane", not Jane and Kerk"

here is [the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-fast-2jpsc?file=/src/Components/Info.js:132-147)

context

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const ContextInfo = createContext();

export const InfoProvider = (props) => {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      company: "Target",
      employee: "Jane"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      company: "Value Right",
      employee: "George"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      company: "Target",
      employee: "Kerk"
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <ContextInfo.Provider value={[address, setAddress]}>
        {props.children}
      </ContextInfo.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

info.js - where the map is located

```
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";

const Info = ({ fltr }) => {
  const testMe = (result, id) => {
    console.log(result.employee);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Container className="pl-1 pr-1 mt-4">
        <h3>General Information</h3>

        {fltr.map((result, id) => (
          <>
            <ul style={{ margin: "0.1rem" }}>
              <li key={result.id}>
                <a href="#" onClick={testMe(result)}>
                  <h5>{result.employee}</h5>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </>
        ))}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
export default Info;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the scope of click function: The correct version is:

```html
< a href="#" onClick={ ()=> { testMe(result); } } >
  < h5> { result.employee }< /h5>
< /a>
```

Full Code

```js
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";

const Info = ({ fltr }) => {
  const testMe = (result, id) => {
    console.log(result.employee);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Container className="pl-1 pr-1 mt-4">
        <h3>General Information</h3>

        {fltr.map((result, id) => (
          <>
            <ul style={{ margin: "0.1rem" }}>
              <li key={result.id}>
                <a
                  href="#"
                  onClick={() => {
                    testMe(result);
                  }}
                >
                  <h5>{result.employee}</h5>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </>
        ))}
      </Container>
      {/* <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-1">
        <Button href="/main" className={style["container-exit-btn"]}>Exit Account</Button>
      </div> */}
    </>
  );
};
export default Info;
```

Comment: it is already marked as the answer, you cant mark it right away you need to wait three min. Would you happen to know how to pass the data to another component via click event?

Comment: do you use react-router ? how is the structure of your app?

Comment: yes, I use react-router, currently, I have the route set up with the endpoint, just not sure how to pass the data from the above component, I am getting a `fltr` prop so not sure if I need to pass it to the sibling component.

Comment: see https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-sample-z6qgu?file=/src/ProjectSingle.js if this helps ( i created this for another question's answer)